# how can return value to component using subscribe in service file?

Tags: angular

I'm using http requests as separate service. Also i'm using authguard as service. after subscribe from authguard service i want to return data to login component. but i can't return data to component.

http service function

```
createp(entity: any, ep:string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post(ep, entity, {responseType: 'text'})
    .pipe(
      tap((reticapp: string) => this.log(`added entity w/ id=${reticapp}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<string>('create'))
    );
  }
```

auth service function

```
login(auth: Auth) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', 'token');

    const loginData: any = {
      email: auth.email,
      password: auth.password
    };
    const url = environment.apiEndpoint + '/pau/v1/ses';

    this.authService.createp(loginData, url).subscribe(result => {
      this.result = result;
    });
}
```

call 'onlogin() function from component

```
onLogin(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.loginUser = {
      email: form.value.email,
      password: form.value.password
    };
    this.authService.login(this.loginUser);
  }
```

I have tried add subscribe to after call authservice. but when it add page refreshed.

I want to get return data to component how can get it?

Comment: Data result is available on `this.result`, did you tried return it?

Comment: @FilipeManuel I have tried. but when It's using on component. It was undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move subscribe into component ts file like this
service:

```
login(auth: Auth) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', 'token');

    const loginData: any = {
      email: auth.email,
      password: auth.password
    };
    const url = environment.apiEndpoint + '/pau/v1/ses';

    this.authService.createp(loginData, url);
}
```

component

```
  onLogin(form: NgForm) {
        if (form.invalid) {
          return;
        }
        this.loginUser = {
          email: form.value.email,
          password: form.value.password
        };
        this.authService.login(this.loginUser).subscribe(result => {
          this.loginResult = result;
        });
      }
```